# How to suppress command output from makefile?

Tags: makefile

My make file looks like:

```
nstop:
    @kill `cat ${APP_ROOT}/run/nginx.pid` ||:
```

But I still get output:

```
$ make nstop
cat: /run/nginx.pid: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
```

How to suppress output from command at backtick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved that by redirecting error output into `/dev/null`:

```
nstop:
    @kill `cat ${APP_ROOT}/run/nginx.pid 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null ||:
```

But, I think, there should be better solution.

Comment: This is a shell question, not a make question.  Make just runs your command in a shell.  It doesn't know about or do anything with the output from your command: it simply checks the exit code.  You can make your text slightly simpler with () as in: `( kill `cat ...` ) 2>/dev/null` so at least you only have to write the redirect once.